# GitLab CI: Using environment variable in exists rule

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want my CI job to only run if a file exists. My path contains environment variable that is passed on the GitLab CI/CD schedule variables.

```
  rules:
     - exists:
        - foo/bla/${ENV}/foo.json
```

When I use the `$ENV` environment variable (with or without curly braces), it does not work (the job is not created). However, when I explicitly state the full path (foo/bla/prod/foo.json), it does work.

My concern is that GitLab does not evaluate the environment variables when they read the rules.

Any help would be appreicated.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible but there exists an open [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/283881) for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

This should be supported with [GitLab 15.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/11/22/gitlab-15-6-released/#cicd-variable-support-in-rulesexists-configuration) (November 2022):

> ### CI/CD variable support in rules:exists configuration
>
> The more complex your `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration is, the more difficult it is to maintain and scale.
>
> By adding support for CI/CD variables with the `rules: exists` keyword, you can now use variables for paths or filenames.
> Having a single source of truth by storing frequently used values in variables ensures consistent behavior and makes your configuration easier to manage.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_6/variable_support_rule_exists.png -- CI/CD variable support in rules:exists configuration]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesexists) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/283881).